# React - parent components render child components to different elements/nodes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an already built site in plain old HTML+SASS and I want to add a little React in to handle the main content of the site. I have a list of internal links in a left col that displays different content in the right column (pretty much like tabs).

Looking at various articles it seems as though I should have a parent component that manages a state (perhaps state.currentTab) to control which main content should be rendered.

My problem is I need the parent component to render the left link and the right content to different elements. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I can see from the below that nothing will actually render as both of the ReactDom.render()'s are in the myParent which never gets called. But my problem seem to be that I need to call/render the two left and right cols in there to be able to pass state updates to each one so I can control the content. And I don't think I can do that if they sit at the bottom of the App.js file which is outside the parent component.

I'm sure I've made some mistakes in the below code but hopefully it explains clearly enough what I want to do.

So the the project might look like so:

index.html

```
body
  .container
    #leftCol <!-- render links to this element -->
    #rightCol <!-- render content to this element -->
```

App.js

```
class myParent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        currentTab: 0
       }
     }
     ReactDOM.render(<Conference currentTab="this.state.currentTab" />,document.getElementById('rightCol'));
     ReactDOM.render(<TabMenu />,document.getElementById('leftCol'));
}

class rightCol extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>right col mark etc</div>
    )
  }
}

class leftCol extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing hard page loads (normal `<a>`s), you can just access the url in constructor in MyParent and render based on that.

```
class myParent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        page: location.pathname.split('/').pop(),
       }
     }
     componentDidMount() {
       ReactDOM.render(<Conference currentTab="this.state.currentTab" />,document.getElementById('rightCol'));
       ReactDOM.render(<TabMenu />,document.getElementById('leftCol'));
     }
     render() {
       if (this.state.page === 'tab1') { ... }
     }
}
```

If you want to change to client side routing, then you'll make the links preventDefault and use pushState. You can use an EventEmitter (`new (require('events').EventEmitter())`) and listen for events in MyParent in componentDidMount. In the children you can dispatch events after doing a pushState. You'll still capture the initial url in MyParent as shown above.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think you get my problem. I'm going to give you suggestion a go. :)

Comment: Hi, sorry but could you please give me a little more guidance on what goes in the `if` statement in the render function? I tried <Conference /> but it just said that it was undefined. I'm also getting console errors abut the <Conference /> inside the componentDidMount(). Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, issue is you defined the `class` name with small letter starting, Use these names: `MyParent RightCol and LeftCol` instead of `myParent rightCol, leftCol`.

**Reason**: If a `React Class` name starts with a lowercase letter then no methods inside the `class` get called, i.e. nothing `Renders`, and you don't get any error message in the `Browser console`, because name starting with small letters are treated as `HTML` elements, its a rule that all `React` components must start with a upper case letter.

Reference: https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/f1f4ba40816e7d7848ad

Comment: This is true, but not the main issue here.